# How to format a date locale-depending in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm on a german pc, with a browser locale set to `de`. Also I included the js lib:

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
```

Problem: `{{mydate | date:'shortDate'}}` still gives me eg `16\05\05`.

But it should print `05.05.16`.

Also, printing numbers like `{{mynumber | number}}` gives me `9.9` instead of `9,9`.

Not surprising angular print for `console.log($locale)` is:

```
id: "en-us"
localeID: "en_US"
```

But why? What might be missing in this case?

Comment: The issue is that your locale is "incorrect". Either it's reset manually or the locale on your OS is set to US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that this inclusion is done after having included angularjs lib first.

Comment: The inclusion is may very last statement in my index.html, so yes.

Comment: I have both files in the `index.html`, `angular.min.js` coming before the locale plugin.

Comment: maybe you should post the entire code here dude, for me to have more visibility :)

Comment: Wait. I just found out I'm loading the locale plugin dynamically. Probably this is too late. Because if I hardcode the js language lib, everything works fine. So you're probably right: order matters.